# How to create multiple instance for one-to-one field in django from base model inheritance?

Tags: python, django

I have two type user model inherit from User model:

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    user_uuid = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True)

    @property
    def is_manager(self):
        return hasattr(self, 'manager')

    @property
    def is_salesman(self):
        return hasattr(self, 'salesman')

class Manager(User):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, parent_link=True, db_column='user_uuid')

class Salesman(User):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, parent_link=True, db_column='user_uuid')
```

Now, the Manager could be a Salesman too. So I want create the manager instance and salesman instance which both inherit from same user instance. I can do it in that way:

```
INSERT INTO t_salesman (`user_uuid`, ...) VALUES ('{manager.user.user_uuid}', ...)
```

then:

```
user = User.objects.get(user_uuid='{manager.user.user_uuid}')
assert user.is_manager == True
assert user.is_salesman == True
```

But I can't create Salesman like below:

```
manager = Manager.objects.first()
salesman = Salesman.objects.create(user=manager.user)  # thanks @Arpit Solanki
assert salesman.user_uuid == manager.user_uuid  # AssertionError, create new user instance
```

Is there any way I can do that through Django model without add row in Salesman table by SQL directly?

Any suggestion will be helpful, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that user param is a User object not a Manager object. Since your Manager model has user attribute you can pass it to Salesman model to create a object with same user. See the example below.

```
manager = Manager.objects.first()
salesman = Salesman.objects.create(user=manager.user)
```

Comment: Thank you for point out my mistake, but it doesn't work, the salesman.user is still not equal manager.user

Comment: what 's the output? Is user empty? Does it does any error?

Comment: No errors, it created a new instance both in User and Salesman, which salesman.user_uuid != manager.user_uuid

Comment: @BinEmber did you try this `assert salesman.user.id == manager.user.id`

Comment: Yes, it raise the AssertionError, there are two different user_uuid

Comment: why are you extending User class in Manager and Salesman. This inheritence is the issue. You are anyway creating a OneToOneField to User so extending through User model is not needed. @BinEmber

Comment: It looks fine until I met this demand, cause I want manage different user in separated model, they have different fields. Now it smell like a bad design... Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: You have a OneToOne field to the User model so you don't need to extend the User class. You can manage different users just with OneToOne fields no need to extend

Comment: Sounds great, looks the `parent_link=True` and inheritance is not necessary too. I'll try, thanks.